# Update/Restart Android Service Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-sharedpreferences

I am very new to Android so this maybe a really basic question:

I have a Service which starts when a user press a button

The service will start a new task and Loop it every N Seconds.
The seconds are set over the Settings Tab in my Android App.

In the OnStart() Method in the service get the preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

And set the Settings, for example:

```
final Long pollInterval = Long.parseLong(settings.getString("pollInterval", "1000"));
```

The Task is Polling on a Database for new entrys.
My Goal is to restart the Service after going back to the main frame so the onCreate method get the new Preferences or to refresh the preferences in the running task to change the Poll interval.

I tried to restart the Service with:

```
startService(serviceIntent);
stopService(serviceIntent);
```

But for any reason this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this one to repeat service



try {

            //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am =
                (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    2*60*60,pendingIntent);

          } catch (Exception e) {}

Also stop service when your task is completed
```